# Use SVG image element to link to SVG in DOM

Tags: svg

I would like to show multiple copies of an SVG image without reproducing the entire DOM representation multiple times.  I was trying to achieve this using the `svg:image` element without any luck

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="tiger1" viewBox="0 0 900 900" version="1.1" width="200" height="200">
    .... contents
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="tiger2" version="1.1" width="200" height="200">
    <image xlink:href="url(#tiger1)" width="200" height="200" x="0" y="0"/>
</svg>
```

The problem is that it seems that `xlink:href` is always interpreting its value as a resource so it's looking for a file named "url(#tiger1)".

Is there a way to use `image` with local DOM references?  Or else is there a different technique for repeating an SVG that exists only in the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<image>` is for complete files, `<use>` is for fragments, something like this...

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="tiger1" viewBox="0 0 900 900" version="1.1" width="200" height="200">
    .... contents
</svg>
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="tiger2" version="1.1" width="200" height="200">
  <use width="200" height="200" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#tiger1" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you. I misread the spec and thought that "use" could not be used for entire <svg> elements. The use element works for me on all browsers I've tried except Safari/Chrome on iOS where no image appears. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Sometimes this is unit problems. Remember that the width and height in  the SVG element should be specified in real units of px, em, cm whatever. When you don't provide real units, the element will take a guess at what you mean - usually CSS pixels. Also, the units inside the use element are viewbox units and are additional transforms to the location of the original content, not replacement values. Sometimes your content is there, it's just outside the viewable area.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, too, but specifying everything in px doesn't work.  Also, if I replace the <use> with the entire <svg> I was linking to it shows up just fine, so I don't think it was just outside the viewable area.  I'm stumped but I must be doing something wrong... it seems too extreme to be a bug.

Comment: After reading the spec a little further I suspect this problem has to do with the fact that I'm trying to reference an element in one SVG from inside another SVG. It doesn't sound like that is technically allowed. Also, it explicitly says <use> should not be allowed to reference an <svg> element but I have the same issue on iOS if I reference a <g> instead if it is is in a different <svg>.

Comment: Hmm, OK.  I was basing it on this http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/linking.html#ReferenceRestrictions (restriction A), but maybe the key is that the "host language" is HTML.  It also says in the table below that <use> must not reference an <svg> element where in the full spec on "use" it defines this behavior.  And I saw another place where it said an <svg> can't be inside another <svg> which I also thought was OK. Maybe the discrepancy is in the "tiny" spec... I suppose browsers target the full spec...